# How to get the user_id of the current user in a telegram bot in Java?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I use Java and [telegrambots](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots) library.  Tell me please. How to get the user_id of the current user in telegram bot? Could you show an example?

```
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {

            String massageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            User user = update.getMessage().getFrom();

            if (massageText.equals("/start")) {

                System.out.println("CurrentUserID --> ");

                startCommandReceived(chatId, update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
            }
        }
```